# Realizar una búsqueda en un array con mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Tengo este código

```
     Teacher.find({
                 'hour.hour_time': '15',
                  $and: [{"hour.pricea": {$gte: 30}},
                         {"hour.priceb": { $lte: 30}}]
                 })
```

que corresponde a esto

```
          "_id": "5ea5b78757447f3ee02f19eb",
          "hour": [
            {
                "_id": "5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ee",
                "hour_time": "15",
                "pricea": 20,
                "priceb": 25
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ed",
                "hour_time": "30",
                "pricea": 25,
```

Cuando realizo la búsqueda no toma en cuenta el tiempo, en este ejemplo el tiempo sería

```
            'hour.hour_time': '15',
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Pero lo que deseas es que traiga sólo los subdocumentos en el `array` *hour*, ya que tal como lo tienes te trae todos los documentos de la colección `teachers` que contengan al menos 1 elemento en `hour` tal que `hour.hour_time` es igual a ´"15"` y que además contenga al menos un elemento tal que `hour.pricea` es mayor o igual que 30 y `hour.priceb` es menor o igual que 30. Por lo cual el resultado de la consulta es correcta. Creo que lo que intentas hacer es filtrar el `array` de subdocumentos. O me equivoco?

Comment: Si eso, par el elemento `hour`, debe tener esos criterios. hour_time:'15'. y el precio se debe encontrar entre `hour.pricea` y `hour.priceb`. Pero no se por que, no  tiene encuentra `hour_time:15` . @MauricioContreras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema está en que el método que usas para obtener el resultado no es el adecuado. Y es que según lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, deseas filtrar un `Array` de tu documento de tal forma que el resultado final arroje sólo los elementos filtrados en dicho `Array`. Sin embargo, el método `find` tal como lo utilizas no hará el filtrado que pretendes.

El método `find` si toma en cuenta el valor `'hour.hour_time': '15'` que estás pasando, de hecho el resultado que obtienes es el esperado al usarse de la forma en la que lo usas. Pero no es el método adecuado para la tarea.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Tienes más de una forma de lograr el resultado esperado. Mostraré al menos 2, que serían las más comunes. Pero antes, explicaré cómo funciona el método `find` en el contexto en el que pretendes usarlo.

**`find()`**

El método `find()` es quizás el más usado en consultas a bases de datos MongoDB. Es muy sencillo de usar, sólo se necesita un documento de filtro y un objeto (opcional) de configuración adicional de búsquedas (opciones).

En el contexto que pretendes usarlo, el método devolverá todos y cada uno de los documentos que coincidan con el siguiente filtro:

```js
{
  'hour.hour_time': '15,
  $and: [
    { 'hour.pricea': { $gte: 30 }},
    { 'hour.priceb': { $lte: 30 }}
  ]
}
```

Este filtro indica una búsqueda en la colección sobre documentos que contengan un campo llamado `hour` y que dicho campo contenga 3 subcampos: `hour_time`, `pricea` y `priceb`.

Si un documento de la colección no contiene un campo llamado `hour`, es inmediatamente descartado del resultado de la búsqueda.

Si el campo `hour` contiene un subdocumento, se verifica que contenga los 3 campos mostrados en el filtro. Si las condiciones no se cumplen, el documento se descarta, si las mismas se cumplen, el documento es agregado a la lista de resultados.

Si el campo `hour` es de tipo `Array`, se buscará en cada elemento de dicho `Array` algún elemento que contenga los 3 campos antes mencionados.

Si ningún elemento del `Array` contiene los 3 campos, se descarta del resultado de la búsqueda.

Si algún elemento del `Array` contiene los 3 campos, y los mismos cumplen las condiciones, el documento se añade a la lista de resultados.

Entonces, dado que `hour` es un campo de tipo `Array`, bastará que alguno de sus elementos cumpla las 3 condiciones y **todo** el documento será añadido a la lista.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos los siguientes 3 documentos en nuestra colección:

```js
[
  {
    _id: '5ea5b78757447f3ee02f19eb',
    hour: [
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ee',
        hour_time: '15',
        pricea: 30,
        priceb: 25
      },
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ed',
        hour_time: '30',
        pricea: 25,
        priceb: 35
      },
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ef',
        hour_time: '40',
        pricea: 15,
        priceb: 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: '5ea5b78757447f3ee02f19ec',
    hour: [
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19fe',
        hour_time: '25',
        pricea: 40,
        priceb: 25
      },
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19fd',
        hour_time: '30',
        pricea: 25,
        priceb: 35
      },
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ff',
        hour_time: '40',
        pricea: 15,
        priceb: 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: '5ea5b78757447f3ee02f19fc',
    hour: [
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19fa',
        hour_time: '15',
        pricea: 20,
        priceb: 25
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

El resultado de una consulta `find` con el filtro usado sería el siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    _id: '5ea5b78757447f3ee02f19eb',
    hour: [
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ee',
        hour_time: '15',
        pricea: 30,
        priceb: 25
      },
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ed',
        hour_time: '30',
        pricea: 25,
        priceb: 35
      },
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ef',
        hour_time: '40',
        pricea: 15,
        priceb: 50
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Sólo el primer documento de la colección mostrada cumple las 3 condiciones, debido al primer elemento de su campo `hour`. Podemos ver el resultado de la consulta en este [MongoPlaygorund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0n5YAtMNtYz).

Y el resultado incluye todos y cada uno de los elementos del campo `hour`. Y esto es así, porque el método `find` devuelve **todo** el documento de la colección.

Por lo tanto, el resultado es el esperado para la consulta realizada. Como puedes observar, si está tomando en cuenta el filtro `hour.hour_time: '15'`, ya que si no lo hiciera, traería todos los documentos que cumplieran sólo las 2 restantes condiciones. Es como si quitáramos esa entrada. Podemos verlo en este otro [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MqUzWPpmzPl), donde se observa que para el mismo conjunto de datos, al quitar la restricción sobre el campo `hour_time`, la consulta devuelve 2 documentos.

**Filtrar el resultado**

Una de las soluciones es filtrar el resultado para *eliminar* del campo `hour` todos los elementos que no cumplan la condición sobre el campo `pricea` y `priceb`.

Si tomamos el resultado obtenido con el método `find`, podemos luego filtrar el campo `hour` y quedarnos con los elementos que satisfacen la condición.

Por ejemplo:

```js
// resultado obtenido al consultar con Teacher.find(...)
const results = [
  {
    _id: '5ea5b78757447f3ee02f19eb',
    hour: [
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ee',
        hour_time: '15',
        pricea: 30,
        priceb: 25
      },
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ed',
        hour_time: '30',
        pricea: 25,
        priceb: 35
      },
      {
        _id: '5ea5b78857447f3ee02f19ef',
        hour_time: '40',
        pricea: 15,
        priceb: 50
      }
    ]
  }
]

const filtrado = results.map(element => {
  element.hour = element.hour.filter(hour => {
    return (hour.pricea >= 30 && hour.priceb <= 30);
  });
  return element;
});

console.log(filtrado);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

De esta forma obtenemos los elementos de `hour` que satisfacen la condición especificada.

**Usar un proceso de Agregación para que Mongo filtre el resultado**

Usando un [proceso de agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) para que sea MongoDB la encargada de procesar y filtrar los datos.

Para ello debemos crear las etapas necesarias del proceso de agregación.

La primera etapa será [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html), la cual hará que los documentos del primer resultado sean aquellos que cumplan la condición: `hour.hour_time: '15'`. Por ejemplo:

```js
const aggregate = [
  { $match: { 'hour.hour_time': '15' }},
  // ...
]
```

En este [MongoPalyground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_T3IfRwydI9), podemos ver el resultado de la etapa `$match`.

La segunda etapa será [`unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html), que nos servirá para crear un documento por cada elemento del campo `hour`, de esta forma luego podremos filtrar los documentos que cumplan las dos condiciones restantes.

```js
const aggregate = [
  { $match: { 'hour.hour_time': '15' }},
  { $unwind: '$hour' }, // <- el nombre del campo debe ir precedido de un signo $
  //...
]
```

Podemos ver el resultado del proceso anterior en este [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aDNxc1MG-Dg), donde se aprecia que el resultado contiene 4 documentos, todos con su propio campo `hour` que ahora ya no es un `Array` sino un documento embebido.

La siguiente etapa nuevamente sería una etapa `$match`, para filtrar sólo aquellos documentos que satisfagan las dos condiciones restantes.

```js
const aggregate = [
  { $match: { 'hour.hour_time': '15' }},
  { $unwind: '$hour' }, // <- el nombre del campo debe ir precedido de un signo $
  { $match: { $and: [ {'hour.pricea': { $gte: 30 }}, {'hour.priceb': {$lte: 30 }}] }},
  //...
]
```

Nuevamente podemos ver un ejemplo del proceso anterior en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yehLVF0vhW0), en el cual se observa que el resultado obtenido ya se asemeja bastante al esperado, sólo falta volver a convertir el campo `hour` en un tipo `Array`.

Esta última etapa será [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html), y agruparemos los documentos por el campo `_id` y luego cada subdocumento del campo `hour` lo añadiremos a un campo `hour` de tipo `Array`, usando el operador [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/). Por ejemplo:

```js
const aggregate = [
  { $match: { 'hour.hour_time': '15' }},
  { $unwind: '$hour' }, // <- el nombre del campo debe ir precedido de un signo $
  { $match: { $and: [ {'hour.pricea': { $gte: 30 }}, {'hour.priceb': {$lte: 30 }}] }},
  { $group:
    {
      _id: '$_id',
      hour: { $push: '$hour' }
    }
  }
]
```

Nuevamente podemos ver el resultado del proceso anterior en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MQ-DWjjTPiM).

Con esto, el resultado devuelto por MongoDB es el que estábamos esperando.

Para usar este proceso de agregación en tu modelo, sólo debes usar el método [`aggregate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate). Por ejemplo:

```js
const aggregateStages = [
  { $match: { 'hour.hour_time': '15' }},
  { $unwind: '$hour' },
  { $match: { $and: [ {'hour.pricea': { $gte: 30 }}, {'hour.priceb': {$lte: 30 }}] }},
  { $group:
    {
      _id: '$_id',
      hour: { $push: '$hour' }
    }
  }
];

Teacher.aggregate(aggregateStages, results => {
  console.log(results);
  // ...
});
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando comparas cadenas de texto, lo recomendable es utilizar [eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/). Te dejo un enlace a la documentación de MongoDB.

Lo que deberías hacer es

```js
Teacher.find({
                 'hour.hour_time' {$eq: '15'},
                  $and: [{"hour.pricea": {$gte: 30}},
                         {"hour.priceb": { $lte: 30}}]
                 })
```